# Can someone break my anti DOM-based XSS javascript function?

Tags: web-application, javascript, xss, secure-coding

Can someone break my anti DOM-based XSS javascript function using `window.location`?

```
    function parseparameters()
    {
        var href = window.location.href;

        var id = href.indexOf('#');

        if (id < 0)
        {
            throw new Error("Error");
        }

        var hash = href.substring(id + 1);

        var spsp = hash.split('&');

        var thereturn = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < spsp.length; i++) 
        {
            spsp[i] = spsp[i].split('=');

            if (spsp[i].length == 2) 
            {
                thereturn[decodeURIComponent(spsp[i][0])] = decodeURIComponent(spsp[i][1]);
            }
        }

        return thereturn;
    }
```

Comment: What are you doing with `thereturn`?  This isn't an example of dom based xss,  therefor there is nothing to break.  `thereturn` can contain an xss payload.  decodeURIComponent() is obviously not an escape function.

Answer (score 4):

You're basically asking, if your object creation through parameterized URL query can be exploited in such a way to load it with an XSS code. The short answer is not unless you plan on using this newly created object for anything. The long answer of course depends on what you plan on doing with this newly created object, will you be sanitizing its properties and function calls, and if you realize this code of yours has nothing to do with mitigation of XSS type attacks, and that it actually enables a potential exploiter to load any object you might be later referencing with malicious payloads and function calls. In essence, your code does nothing else but splits parameterized URL query after the `#` into an object structure:

**this URL:**

```
mywebsite.com#method1=document.location.href%3D%22do.not.ever.open.me%22
```

**into this object:**

```
var myObject = {
    method1 : "document.location.href=\"do.not.ever.open.me\""
};
```

Is this object safe to use? If you still don't know the answer, then my answer has to be: **no**!

**Explanation:**

As you didn't include how these values will be used later in your code, we can't really answer how safe they are to use. But you shouldn't consider them as any safer than a non-parsed hash part of your URI otherwise is, and at the same time does nothing for the rest of your URL, up until the `#` part of it.

**Demonstration:**

To demonstrate, where is the problem, imagine this scenario:

```
obj = new Object();
obj.something = parseparameters().method1;
eval(obj.something);
```

What happened is the web browser loaded the passed URI. Go ahead, it's safe to try it yourself, as I made it so it merely loads this location as a relative path to the opener document URL, resulting in `mywebsite.com/do.not.ever.open.me` location being requested. Changing it to fully qualified path, or indeed to change something else than merely load a new URI, is however still utterly trivial and using `decodeURIComponent()` doesn't change that a bit.

Comment: `method1` is actually the string `function(){document.location.href="do.not.ever.open.me"}`.

Comment: @Gumbo - True, but that doesn't change anything for the answer. It all depends on how these properties will be later used, while the URL parsing itself does nothing to mitigate potential XSS type attacks. See Rook's comment if my answer is not as easy to follow. If you think the answer should be changed to be more factually correct, please feel free to suggest an edit, I certainly won't mind. But consider these strings will later be used somewhere, and we haven't got a clue how. Will OP be evaluating them? Loading as function calls? We just don't know, but fact remains:- it's not XSS safe.

Comment: @Gumbo - OK I edited my answer to include further explanation why it does nothing to prevent XSS. I hope it's now clearer, even though it makes it a lot more speculative for the part where I had to assume a use-case for these strings being parsed into an object. Oh, and I cleared my answer from before a bit, so it's not confusing with for the example non-relevant strings.

Comment: Your example still gives the wrong impression. Any user input is harmful if it’s evaluated.

Comment: @Gumbo - I find this to be a case of nitpicking now, really. What would you want me to add? All the possible XSS exploits for a code we don't have? I wanted to show this code from OP can carry a potentially malicious payload just as well as a URL that he's supposedly sanitizing with this code can. I believe I've managed to show that with, admittedly, speculative approach. Sadly, that's all we have to work with. If you have more information, then please don't hesitate to add your answer, but I'm done with mine. I don't feel there's anything left to say on the matter.

Comment: I’m sorry, but I find the whole example an unfortunate choice. It’s obvious that the posted function does not do anything magical besides parsing name/value pairs and populating an object with them. Your example, that evaluates a passed value, is rather confusing. It should be obvious that evaluating a value from user input is not a good idea.